# How often should I follow up with a contact who is a fellow Alumni?

Tags: job-search, follow-up, sales

I've been keeping contact with a fellow Alumni that is a sales manager hoping to hire fellow alumni at his company, but his company is on a hiring freeze until June.

How often should I follow up with the fellow Alumni to show that I'm interested in the position, but not seem desperate for the position?

Comment: Personally, I would not think of it as following up about the position, but perhaps sharing what is going on with my life and career with the alumni and keeping myself in the other person's mind.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere i think that is terrible advice. Annually is too far apart to build a relationship, so why are you even bothering at that stage? You might as well say "when it benefits you" and then, because that will be apparantly so mercenary to said alumni, not make the effort at all!

Comment: As an aside, I always thought the singular form was 'alumnus' - is that correct? Outmoded? Never used?

Comment: @peterG 'alumnus' is the proper singular form, however, I feel very few people use it (Latin grammar that is not commonly known). I use the slang 'alum', but that's just me.

Comment: People often get Latin wrong on internet fora.

Answer (score 2):

> How often should I follow up with the fellow Alumni to show that I'm
>   interested in the position, but not seem desperate for the position?

If you know there is a hiring freeze until June, I would send your contact an email expressing your interest a **week before the hiring freeze** is set to expire.

If you do not hear back from your contact, I would send another follow up email 2 weeks **after** the hiring freeze is lifted.

At this point if they are *able and or interested* in hiring you, they will get back to you with some sort of feedback.

Examples of expected feedback could be: the hiring freeze was extended, please submit you application through our online portal so we can get the hiring process going, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If this person is an alumni, and they're hiring for a sales role, then I'm not sure why you think you are only following up about the job itself.

A better bet would be to follow up and ask for a coffee to discuss the industry as a whole and how you might fit into it, and general advice.

People love giving advice and their thoughts on the industry, and they like it when people are interested in their thoughts and advice. Also, as this person is a sales manager they are definitely looking for people they can get along with to hire - sales people can be pretty insufferable sometimes for their managers!

You perhaps should not be thinking about talking to this person about a job, but about the overall picture. This will show them you're not just interested in money, but actually interested in the industry. Which is more helpful for securing a role, believe it or not.

So, to answer your question - why not make this person your mentor? Even if you're not a right fit for this company, they will know people in other companies (they are in sales) which will be helpful.

I would suggest asking them for a coffee to talk, and if you and this person get along, schedule a coffee chat each month.